# Button type submit Vs Input type submit | laravel 8

Tags: html, css, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-8

I have a form to register a student.

***The form submits when i use the following code***

```
        <div class="text-xs-right">
            <i class="ti-save-alt"></i> <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded mb-5" value="Register">
        </div>
```

***But it just refreshes if i use the Button type Submit (below code)***

```
          <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary btn-outline">
                 <i class="ti-save-alt"></i> Register
          </button>
```

Can someone please help me understand what am i doing wrong here?
I tried to check if there is any jquery/Js Conflicts by commenting out the scripts. Nothing works.

*I need to have the button working, as i am using fa icons to style them.*

Thank in advance.

My full form code

```
                   <form class="form" method="post" action="{{ route('learner.store') }}">
                    @csrf
                        <div class="box-body">
                            <h4 class="box-title text-info"><i class="ti-user mr-15"></i> Personal Info</h4>
                            <hr class="my-15">

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>CPR Number</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="cprnumber" class="form-control" placeholder="CPR Number" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                                    </div>
                                    @error('cprnumber')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror

                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>First Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name">
                                    </div>
                                    @error('firstname')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Middle Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="middlename" class="form-control" placeholder="Middle Name">
                                    </div>
                                    @error('middlename')
                                    <span class="text-info">{{ $message }}</span>
                                    @enderror

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Last Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Gender</label>
                                        <select name="learnergender" id="select" required class="form-control">
                                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                            <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                            <option value="Female">Female</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Date of Birth</label>
                                        <input type="date" name="learnerdob"  class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Nationality</label>
                                        <select name="learnernationality" id="select" required class="form-control">
                                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                            <option value="Bahraini">Bahraini</option>
                                            <option value="Non-Bahraini">Non Bahraini</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Marital Status</label>
                                        <select name="learnermaritalstatus" id="select" required class="form-control">
                                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                            <option value="Single">Single</option>
                                            <option value="Married">Married</option>
                                            <option value="Divorced">Divorced</option>
                                            <option value="Widowed">Widowed</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>


                            <h4 class="box-title text-info"><i class="ti-save mr-15"></i> Contact Details</h4>
                            <hr class="my-15">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>E-mail</label>
                                        <input type="email" name="learneremail" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Mobile Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="learnermobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Building Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="buildingnumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Building Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Road Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="roadnumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Road Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Block Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="blocknumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Block Number">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Area</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="area" class="form-control" placeholder="Area">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <h4 class="box-title text-info"><i class="ti-save mr-15"></i> Education Details</h4>
                            <hr class="my-15">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Education Level</label>
                                        <select name="educationlevel" id="select" required class="form-control">
                                            <option value="">Select</option>
                                            <option value="Primary">Primary</option>
                                            <option value="Preparatory">Preparatory</option>
                                            <option value="Secondary">Secondary</option>
                                            <option value="Diploma">Diploma</option>
                                            <option value="Bachelor">Bachelor</option>
                                            <option value="Masters/PHD">Masters/PHD</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                              <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Grade</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="learnergrade" class="form-control" placeholder="Grade">
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Graduation Date</label>
                                        <input type="date"  name="graduationdate"  class="form-control" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>


                            <h4 class="box-title text-info"><i class="ti-save mr-15"></i> Organisation Details</h4>
                            <hr class="my-15">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Organisation</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="organisation"  class="form-control" placeholder="Organisation">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Office E-mail</label>
                                        <input type="email" name="officeemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Office E-mail">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Office Number</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="officenumber" class="form-control" placeholder="Office Phone">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Position</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="position" class="form-control" placeholder="Position">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label>Department</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="department" class="form-control" placeholder="Department">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                              <label>Description</label>
                              <textarea rows="5" name="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description/Remarks/Notes"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.box-body -->
                        <div class="box-footer">
                            <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-rounded btn-warning btn-outline mr-1">
                                <i class="ti-trash"></i> Cancel
                            </button>
                            <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-rounded btn-primary btn-outline">
                                 <i class="ti-save-alt"></i> Register
                            </button> -->
                            <div class="text-xs-right">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-rounded mb-5" value="Register">
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </form>
```

**Store method**

```
    public function LearnerManagementStore(Request $request){
    $validatedData =$request->validate([
        'cprnumber' => 'required|unique:learner_management',
        'firstname' => 'required',
        'lastname' => 'required',
        'learnerdob' => 'required',
        'learneremail' => 'required',
        'learnermobile' => 'required',
        ]);

    $data = new LearnerManagement();
    $data->cprnumber = $request->cprnumber;
    $data->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $data->middlename = $request->middlename;
    $data->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $data->learnergender = $request->learnergender;
    $data->learnerdob = $request->learnerdob;
    $data->learnernationality = $request->learnernationality;
    $data->learnermaritalstatus = $request->learnermaritalstatus;
    $data->learneremail = $request->learneremail;
    $data->learnermobile = $request->learnermobile;
    $data->buildingnumber = $request->buildingnumber;
    $data->roadnumber = $request->roadnumber;
    $data->blocknumber = $request->blocknumber;
    $data->area = $request->area;
    $data->educationlevel = $request->educationlevel;
    $data->learnergrade = $request->learnergrade;
    $data->graduationdate = $request->graduationdate;
    $data->organisation = $request->organisation;
    $data->officeemail = $request->officeemail;
    $data->officenumber = $request->officenumber;
    $data->position = $request->position;
    $data->department = $request->department;
    $data->description = $request->description;
    $data->save();

    $notification = array (
        'message' => 'Learner Added successfully',
        'alert-type' => 'success'
    );

    return redirect()->route('learners.viewall')->with($notification);
}
```

**Route**

```
// Learner Management
Route::prefix('learner')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/viewall', [LearnerController::class, 'LearnerManagementViewall'])-> name('learners.viewall'); 
    Route::get('/view/{id}', [LearnerController::class, 'LearnerManagementView'])-> name('learner.view'); 
    Route::get('/add', [LearnerController::class, 'LearnerManagementAdd'])-> name('learner.add'); 
    Route::post('/store', [LearnerController::class, 'LearnerManagementStore'])-> name('learner.store'); 
    Route::get('/edit/{id}', [LearnerController::class, 'LearnerManagementEdit'])-> name('learner.edit'); 
    Route::post('/update/{id}', [LearnerController::class, 'LearnerManagementUpdate'])-> name('learner.update'); 
    Route::get('/delete/{id}', [LearnerController::class, 'LearnerManagementDelete'])-> name('learner.delete'); 
});
```

Comment: try : add `@method('POST')` to form. set `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: You can omit `type` if your `button` element is inside a `form`

Comment: @DarpanKulkarni Doesnt work

Comment: solve : use script code for submit form : onclick="$('#my-form').submit()"

Comment: @MohammadrezaGolshahi I have already set the method as post. Setting enctype doesnt work either.

Comment: Please show me your `store` method `route('learner.store')`

Comment: @MohammadrezaGolshahi The onclick event works well. But it is kind of giving a popup prompt "The following data would have been submitted to the server: 
..."

Comment: @DarpanKulkarni I have added the store method in my question.

Comment: Can you show us the route? from web.php file

Comment: @MohammadrezaGolshahi any suggestion how i can avoid that warning?

Comment: Do you use `datatable` in your project? /  To solve the problem you have to share the project source

Comment: @MohammadrezaGolshahi - adding `@method('POST')` is superfluous if the method is already set out in the opening `<form>` tag. `enctype="multipart/form-data"` would only be required if there are files being uploaded.

Comment: I cannot replicate this. I have set up a clean install of Laravel 8, with all your routes and the required methods in the Controller (although the store method just outputs "I got this far", rather than doing the full processing that yours does) and the form submits without issue whether you are using the first or second method.

Comment: try to add a trailing slash to the "learner.store" route url